# Passar vetor por referencia ou valor?

Tags: c, funções, declaração-de-variável, passagem-por-referência, passagem-por-valor

Quero criar duas funções, uma é para preencher um vetor com números aleatórios. A outra função é para mostrar o conteúdo do vetor preenchido.
Então fiz da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int vetor[5];

void inicia(int v[5]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        v[i] = 1 + rand() % 20;
    }
}

void mostra(int v[5]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%d", v[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    void inicia(int vetor[5]);
    void mostra(int vetor[5]);

    return 0;
}
```

Eu queria entender o pq da função "mostra" não está imprimindo o valor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários erros no seu código, especialmente de declaração de variáveis e funções quando na verdade só vai usá-las, mas nenhum que está na pergunta. Você só define o tipo da variável ou função quando está declarando, quando vai acessar a variável ou chamar a função, não pode colocar o tipo, então nem está chamando nada.

Um *array* já é passado por referência sempre.

Aproveitei para dar uma organizada e modernizada, e melhorei o escopo. Não crie variáveis globais a não ser que saiba porque está fazendo isto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void inicia(int v[5]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) v[i] = 1 + rand() % 20;
}

void mostra(int v[5]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d\n", v[i]);
}

int main() {
    int vetor[5];
    inicia(vetor);
    mostra(vetor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/y1QUkf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/osdxoyrf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Reference.c).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mano!